# Spherical Lens to 2D coordinates (conversion)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to build a circle detector to find the centers of circles. I am using a 180-degree camera for a wider field of view, but this means that I need to somehow translate the coordinates. My algorithm thinks it's reading to actual x/y coordinates based on the distortion due to the lens. Any idea of how I can mathematically describe and implement this relationship?

Thanks! I've attached a pic of my LabVIEW front panel for context:

[image: Circle Detector Demo]

Comment: What is the brand/model of your camera? (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens#Mapping_function)